# C# Substring Alternative - Return rest of line within string after character

Tags: c#, substring

I have some code that reads a text file and sets it to a string. Each line of the text file contains separate data parameters that I a trying to extract. Here is an small example of how the string/text file is laid out:

```
...
part=XYZ
quantity=123
weight=14
length=60
...
```

Is there a good way to return everything after "=" on a given line?

I currently got it to work using substring, but I'm curious if there is a more concise way to get the same result. Here is the code I currently have:

```
    strStart = partData.IndexOf("part=") + 5;
    strEnd = partData.IndexOf(" ", strStart);
    string partNum = partData.Substring(strStart, strEnd - strStart);
```

***Additional Clarification***

I will be extracting multiple variables from the text file. For example, given the data above I would extract the 4 variables:

partNum = "XYZ"

qty = "123"

wght = "14"

len = "60"

Comment: `string.Split()` on `=`

Comment: `Substring` has an overloaded method that returns the rest of the string. It can be replaced with `partData.Substring(strStart)` Check the doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your edit is unfair, because it drastically changes the requirements of the question after you received several answers that address the original question. If you now have a different question that has different requirements, post a new question and ask it there. Your original question did not ask about extracting multiple values - it asked about a more concise way to get the portion to the right of the equals sign, which is what several of us answered.

Comment: I don't feel I  changed the question. I stated from the beginning the text file was read to a string in the given format. The given format contain several lines. The only thing I changed was giving the lines unique values to make it simpler to understand how I was extracting the separate data.

Comment: I agree with @SincereApathy - the question did include all the relevant parts before the edit. To me it looks as if some users skimmed the question instead of actually reading the details, and jumped to conclusions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it much more concisely.

```
string partNum = partData.Substring(partData.IndexOf("=") + 1);
```

This uses the overloaded version of [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that only accepts one parameter, the starting position in the string. It continues from that point to the end of the string.

Clearly this only works if you're certain that there is equals sign in your `partData`, but so would the original code you posted.

Comment: This returns EVERYTHING after the first "=" in the string. I only want to return the rest of the line that starts with "part=" or "weight=" or "quantity=" (I just used "part=" as an example, because I assumed I could take it from there to get the other variables.) So, what I'm looking for might not be after the first "=" in the string and I don't want it to return anything from lines below the line it is on.

Comment: The string you posted (and used as an example) was `part=XYZ`, and the code I posted returns `XYZ` (which is what you asked for it to do). If your requirements are different than you said, or the file is different than what you included, then edit your question so that it correctly states the problem you're trying to solve. My code answers the question you asked at the time I posted my answer. Are you now saying that everything you've shown as separate lines is actually all on one line? Because that's **not** what your question says, even after your edit.

Comment: @KenWhite So much for the picture... ;)

Comment: @Lucero: The way this site works is to answer the question **asked**, not the question you imagine the poster might want to do in the future. I (and the others) answered the question asked. I'm strongly tempted to roll back the inappropriate edit that changed the requirements well after people had posted answers to the original question.

Comment: I'm using `StreamReader(textfile)` to read the textfile and assign it to a string. So, `string partData = reader.ReadToEnd();`.The data is on separate lines in the text file and if I do a `MessageBox.Show(partData)` it shows it on separate lines in the message box. I apologize if I'm misunderstanding how it works and it isn't, in fact, on separate lines within the string variable.

Comment: @KenWhite If you read the very first paragraph (which is unchanged in the edit btw.) it states that the file is read into one string with the specified layout. The edit is really a clarification IMHO, and not inappropriate.

Comment: @Lucero: If you read the entire question (in it's original state), the question was about how to make the three included lines of code more concise. No more, no less. *I currently got it to work using substring, but I'm curious if there is a more concise way to get the same result. Here is the code I currently have:* is extremely clearly stated, and there's no ambiguity about the questioner's meaning whatsoever. The question asked was answered.

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry, but you're wrong. His code sample finds the end position as to extract just a fragment of the string and not the full remainder. He did use the `substring(start, length)` for a valid reason!

Comment: @Lucero: Not according to the sample file content he posted as well. Sorry, but I'm not the one that is wrong. (Actually, the one who is wrong is the poster of the question who did such a poor job of stating the question, posted misleading/inaccurate sample data, and apparently did not ask the question that he really wanted answered.)

Comment: @KenWhite I appreciate your attempt to help me with my problem, and perhaps I didn't ask the question in the best possible way. However, I did state that the text file contains separate lines and I was looking to return only the rest of the line after "=". Also, the code I posted had a length calculation that also indicated what I was looking for. Here is a fiddle of your answer run on the data sample I provided: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kmxjxj , which doesn't return the desired result.

Comment: @KenWhite Also, I respect that you have a broad knowledge of programming. I aspire to get to the point where I know the perfect question to ask. At this point, I'm very early on in my quest to learn programming. This site is a resource to help each other learn and it only works with all levels of experience represented. If everyone knew what they needed to do and ask - the site would serve no purpose. I'm sorry for posting a "discussion", but it strikes a nerve that you attack me for a misunderstanding that was at least clear enough for some others to understand.

Comment: @SincereApathy: The code I posted works on the example you provided, based on your statement that *the text file contains separate lines* and your code that demonstrated working on *a single line*. If your text file is different, that's not my fault. As far as *at least clear enough for some others*, a single user was able to *guess* what you meant, while at least two others besides me (for at least three people) understood it differently. It's **your responsibility** to properly state the problem and explain it to us, new or not; it's not **our job** to *guess what you really mean*.

Comment: @KenWhite It's not worth arguing into oblivion. However, a combined assessment of my opening paragraph and the code I wrote, should drive home the fact that I am searching for the line containing "part=" within a mult-line string and returning the remainder of that line. I posted my sample code as a supplement to the question from the start.

Comment: @SincereApathy: Yes, you're absolutely right. It's not worth arguing. I'll let your own words decide. *I currently got it to work using substring, but I'm curious if there is a more concise way to get the same result. Here is the code I currently have:* is a clear statement of what you're asking - a **more concise way to get the same result**, which you were provided. Your changing the requirements after the fact was inappropriate; the question you asked was answered. No problem, though. Good luck to you in the future.

Comment: @KenWhite Since I still feel I asked the question in a correct way to get my results and never changed the requirements (I'll admit I may be wrong outside of my own head), and I think you now know what I was ultimately after. Can you tell me how you might have worded the question differently? Just curious so I don't repeat this mistake.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102821/discussion-between-sincereapathy-and-ken-white).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a regex to do this; it can handle more complex cases than the simple `IndexOf` or `Split` solutions, such as skipping whitespaces around the `=` or not match certain patterns, or extract all the components found in a single line at once.

```
string partNum = Regex.Match(partData, @"=(.*)$", RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups[1].Value;
```

The regex will be slower for the simple case (such as just splitting on the `=`), but if you actually want to process and extract data from a halfway complex pattern it will be more efficient and more concise as well.

Also, by checking the `Success` property on the match, you could validate that the data is conforming to the expected pattern along the way without requiring any additional processing/verification logic.

Here's an example which extracts the parts before and after the = sign for each text line which is using the expected pattern in the string, and trims the parts along the way:

```
for (Match match = Regex.Match(partData, @"^\s*([^=]+?)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline); 
        match.Success;
        match = match.NextMatch()) {
    // this code runs for each line in your string which has the expected pattern
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string value = match.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

**Edit:** [Here's a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fi7fGi) which does show how this code works with your sample data.

Comment: Ugh. *I have a simple Substring question.* to which you respond *Let's make it much worse by introducing a totally unnecessary regular expressino into the mix.* This is the equivalent of telling a user who asks how to add two integer values to convert them to floating point, perform the calculation, convert it to a string and use Substring to remove the decimal point, and then convert it back to an integer.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm trying to step back and look at the picture. The OP explicitly states that he is trying to extract data from lines of a text file, and that's where the regex solution may be the better approach indeed. I did write from the very beginning that the regex is not the ideal choice for the simple case - but I try to show options for achieving the task at hand.

Comment: Nonsense. There's no complexity to any sort of pattern. It's two values separated by '='. The overhead of the regex is simply unnecessary. There's a difference between looking at the picture and what you're doing here. Regular expressions have their place, but this is definitely not one of them. (Notice I didn't downvote; while I think your answer is absolutely the wrong approach to take, *technically* it would work. It's vast overkill, but it would *work*.)

Comment: @KenWhite Fair enough, I respect your opinion but I don't agree (and I didn't downvote either ;) ). I work on parsers, state machines and finite automata on a daily basis so I might be more fond of regex than the average user, but these "simple" patterns often get extended with string trimming, validity checks, recognizing other patterns licke comment or empty lines etc. and that's where the mess begins IMHO.

Comment: @Lucero I like how this works. Each file can contain a variable number of parameters and this allows me to get only the ones in the file without having to write IF statements to check if all possible parameters exist and extract if they do. One question. How can I use the for loop to assign all "values" to separate strings "key" so that I can use them outside of the loop in subsequent code? (Perhaps this warrants another question)

Comment: @SincereApathy Yes, that might be another question - but the answer is actually not that complicated. Assuming that the keys in your file are distinct, you could for instance create a `Dictionary<string, string>` variable outside of the loop, and add the key and value to it in the loop. Then you can retrieve values from the dictionary, or enumerate over them, whatever you need. [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P2p8Cx)

Comment: @SincereApathy - I provided an alternative to access the parameters outside the loop before you mentioned it here ;)  I'm going to have to agree with Ken W. here, re: this answer is like taking a sledge hammer to mosquito. That said, Lucero has a much higher understanding of RegEx than us mere mortal devs.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the text file is in the format posted and **only** contains the data parameters, an alternative approach would be to read the contents of the file and project the contents into a dictionary since you already know the parameter names, i.e,. "part", "quantity", etc...

```
Dictionary<string, string> param = File
    .ReadLines("path.to.file.txt")
    .Select(x => x.Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0], y => y[1]);
```

The contents can then be accessed by the key name, similar to how you were originally assigning the variables:

```
string partNum = param["part"];
```

Or, just use the dictionary as needed without assigning to a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split, it can be easier to read:

```
string value = partData.Split('=', 2)[1];
```

Beware that can throw an exception if there's no '=' on the line.

Answer (score 0):

This will be more robust if you use

```
var parts = string.Split('=')
```

Who knows if someone decides to put a space before or after the equal sign? That would break your existing solution because it would not find "part =XXX". With split you get the parts on either side.